# Searchkick Where Clause in Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm performing a search and want to display everything, but only search on a specific column, instead of all columns.

My table consists of 4 columns, and I only want to query against `party` column, in SQL would be

```
select * from rsvp where party like '%search%'
```

I currently have the below code but is giving me back results where `search` is in either of the four columns

```
@rsvps = Rsvp.search params[:search], field: [:party], page: params[:page], per_page: 15
```

I attempted this code

```
@rsvps = Rsvp.search params[:search], where: {party: params[:search]}, page: params[:page], per_page: 15
```

And this

```
@rsvps = Rsvp.search "*", where: {party: params[:search]}, page: params[:page], per_page: 15
```

But either one don't bring back results.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it right, you need to use `fields` instead of `field`

```
@rsvps = Rsvp.search params[:search], fields: [:party], page: params[:page], per_page: 15
                                           ^
                                           |
                                      s is missing
```

Comment: golly, I feel dumb now, ha..thank you, the search is working now!

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad if it worked out! The devil is in the details ;)